# Join the two EditBox into 1 EditBox in Android

Tags: android, editbox

I am new in android.
I want to join two EditBox into 1 EditBox.
Anyone can help me here.
Thanks in Advance.
[image: I am adding the screen shot that i need]

Comment: Why u want to join them its better if u create Separate EditTexts for Start and end location

Comment: You can't make two edittext into one. you need to use two edittext and design your application to look like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give background to a linear layout with vertical orientation and add two transparent text box in it.

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background_of_big_edittext"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/color_of_your_divider" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if you are talking about the UI. But you can take the texts from the edit text by get text method. Why cant you join both the texts to a single string and use the combined string in program?

Comment: I know how to add 2 strings. but i want to join two editbox shown in screen shot.